# How do I create a generic reducer plugin, that fires on all forms?

Tags: redux-form

Currently my code works, but only for the forms specified specifically in the combine reducer function. But, I would like to have my code work generally for all forms loaded in my single page app.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
export default combineReducers({
  someReducer,
  anotherReducer,
  form: formReducer.plugin({
    specificFormId: (state, action) => { // <-- I don't want this only for specificFormId, I want this to happen for all my forms,
                                        // or at least have a dynamic way of adding more forms
      const {type, payload} = action;
      switch(type) {
        case 'RESET_LINK_TYPE_FIELDS': {
          return {
            ...state,
            registeredFields: {
              ...state.registeredFields,
              // Do some custom restting here based on payload
            }
          };
        }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
  })
});
```

So, anytime my `<Field ..of a certain type/>` fires off this the RESET_LINK_TYPE_FIELDS action, I want the correct form to respond to it.

In the action payload, I can specifically the form identifier or anything else I would need to make this work.

In fact, if the .plugin let me do my own form state slicing, I could easily do this, but because it forces me to pass an object, with a hardcoded form identifier it doesn't work.

Is there a way to have the plugin give me the WHOLE form state, and then I will slice as needed, and return state as needed based on payload?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to do this with the existing API.

You *could* jury rig a solution by wrapping the `redux-form` reducer in your own thing.

```
export default combineReducers({
  someReducer,
  anotherReducer,
  form: resetHack(formReducer)
})

function resetHack(formReducer) {
  return (state, action) => {
    if(action.RESET_LINK_TYPE_FIELDS) {
      // manipulate slice somehow
    } else {
      return formReducer(state, action)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea I was worried about that. The main reason I'm doing any of this is to allow dynamic updating of field drop-down values. That is to say anytime a Field SOME_TYPE changes, I change the drop-down values of another dropdown field, taking into consideration the original value. You have provided a similar example using cities and the plugin, but again it hardcodes the forms. I want it to work for every form. Only thing I've come up with is to modify my main "PAGE" reducer, that provides the Form JSON to begin with. And I'm modifying it directly. Any downsides to this?

Comment: I'm not entirely following your intentions. But, in life and in code, sometimes dirty hacks are required.

Comment: My intention is that sometimes one drop-down has to be populated, based on another drop-down, with an ASYNC call in between. FIELD1 > CHANGE > ASYNC > CHANGE DROPDOWN VALUES FIELD 2. And to have this behavior generic for all my forms with a Field TYPE ASYC. Does that make sense? I just want to find the best way to do this with the redux-form framework because I love it otherwise!